# probability of getting at least 3 heads or less?

Tags: probability

I am working on  a homework question:

Suppose you toss 10 fair coins. What is the probability of getting at least 3 heads or less?

I know how to calculate each one separately but how to join them with or? if that is what the question is asking for.

Comment: "at least 3 heads or less"?!  That's 1

Comment: Do you mean to say "At most 3 heads" instead?

Comment: this is the result I got when I calculated it. the question exactly says : "Suppose you toss 10 fair coins. What is the probability of getting at 3 heads or less?" I am not sure if it is a type or it means something?

Comment: Here's an idea.  If the question was just for practice and not for a grade... ignore it.  Throw it in the trash.  Instead, for practice answer the two related questions, "What is the probability that when tossing ten fair coins you get at least three heads? (meaning you tossed 3, 4, 5, ..., 9, or 10 heads)"  And answer the question "What is the probability that when tossing ten fair coins you get at most three heads? (meaning you tossed 0, 1, 2, or 3 heads)."  The original question is either very misleading or has a bad typo.

Comment: Thank you, how to combine at most three heads with or less? P(a)+p(b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is badly phrased, but if you mean AT MOST $3$ heads, then it's just equal to $$P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+P(3)=\frac{1}{1024}\left(\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{1024}(1+10+45+120)=\frac{176}{1024}=\frac{11}{64}$$